# How to bypass validation for a button in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have an ASP.NET form that takes input from a user. There's a `Submit` button on the form and a button called `Calc` which does a calculation to populate a text field. The problem I'm having is that on the form I have a set of `<ASP:REQUIREDFIELDVALIDATOR>` validators and when the `Calc` button is pressed the form gets validated. I don't want the required fields to be validated when the `Calc` button is pressed, only the `Submit` button. Any way around this?

Comment: In ASP.NET Core (because of tag helpers) you can now just add the [`formnovalidate`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formnovalidate.asp) attribute as usual on the `<button>` directly.

Comment: If anyone is working with WebForms, but is using the HTML5 `required` property, you can use `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` on your button to prevent the required check.

Comment: If anyone is working with Razor Pages, you can use formnovalidate="formnovalidate"

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Set the `CausesValidation` property to false.

Answer (score 26):

```
<asp:Button runat="Server" ... CausesValidation="False" />
```

[Button.CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx) (If I remember correctly).

Answer (score 5):

Try putting `CausesValidation="false"` as a button attribute.

Some sample code:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/04/421647.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> **ASPX Page:**

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonNew" runat="server" Text="New" CausesValidation="False" />
```

**OR**

> **CodeBehind Page: (.cs)**

```
buttonNew.CausesValidation = false;
```

Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.100).aspx) to know more about `Validated` and `Validating` events for the controls.

Answer (score 3):

Set the button.causesValidation to false.

[this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx)

However, if all it is doing is calculating something based on user input then you shouldn't have it posting back at all. I would recommend using an HTML button and attach some javascript to it to do your work for you and then you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

While designing the button, you can set its property CausesValidation="false" to avoid validation on button click event. It does not allow to validation the server control and perform its click event only

Answer (score 1):

You should use this

`UseSubmitBehavior="False"`

Answer (score 0):

To disable validation in a specific control

Set the control's CausesValidation property to false.

```
<asp:Button id="Button3" runat="server"
  Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="False">
</asp:Button>
```

To disable a validation control

```
Set the validation controls Enabled property to false.
```

To disable client-side validation

```
Set the validation controls EnableClientScript property to false.
```

[For More Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt244wbb.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)